# Energy Loss during Sharing of Charge between two Capacitors

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, charge, conductors

It is fairly easy to show that there is always a loss energy when two capacitors share their charge to attain the same common potential, but is it with the same ease that one can explain why it actually happens ?

I understand that that there is no implicit assumption of Ohmic/radiation losses within the derivation of the magnitude of energy loss (it is always proportional to the square of the initial P.D. the 2 capacitors). Let they be connected by a wire of ideally negligble resistance (this is where the my textbook fails, where it is written that the loss may be Ohmic), and be made a perfectly closed system. But, the math says that the energy loss issue is still inevitable. But, then, where does the energy go ?

P.S. : Some answers in the internet mention about the issue of infinite current in zero second and terms like the **Dirac Pulse** or the **Delta function**, which, is ofcourse beyond my present understanding.

Comment: I don't know, but I can make an educated (?) guess.  Once the capacitors are connected, and the potential difference established, there is a force on the charge carriers.  They accelerate.  But they eventually stop.  I would guess that the energy is converted to thermal energy upon stopping.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect two lossless capacitors in parallel, charge will flow back and forth. The loop formed by them will store energy in the form of magnetic energy (due to the current flowing) and you will end up with a resonant circuit. The frequency of resonance will be determined by the series capacitance and the inductance of the loop.  So there will not be a true equilibrium - energy is changing from electrostatic to magnetic and back. The accelerating charges will emit EM radiation, and ultimately that is how the energy is radiated and "lost".

This is in fact the principle behind the spark gap transmitter - the very earliest form of radio.

There is no need to invoke "infinite current" since the circuit must have finite size, and thus inductance. The inductance, no matter how small, will prevent infinite current from flowing - it limits the rate of change of current according to

$$- L \frac{dI}{dt} = V$$

Comment: Wont the acceleration of the charges depend upon the length or the dimension of the wire? It is not mentioned in the problem. Or is the net enery emitted the same, irrespective of the dimensions of the wire?

Comment: You are right that there is a "per cycle" aspect to all this - but before thing settle to the steady state half the energy will be lost independent of the dimensions of the wire yes.